# PHP Error Redirect on validation

Tags: php, validation

ive been setting upa simple login for my php . but instead of the php code validating the login it gives me a screen of the codes. here is the form

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" action="checklogin.php" method="post">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
```

and this is the validation named checklogin.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and     password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){


session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

newbie php here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php is a server side language. You cannot run it offline. You need to get a host to host and test your code. Google 'Web free hosting'. The first one is good. Put your code on their and visit the site you chose.

PHP cannot be run client side.

Cheers

Comment: im using a localhost xampp

Comment: Are you sure you set it up right? To test, make a php file and make it "echo "Hello World" and let me know if it runs

Comment: No problem, please press the ^ arrow on the answer to help me out ;)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_register() in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\checklogin.php on line 32

Comment: Hmmm, try setting the variable directly: $_SESSION['variableName'] = "blah" instead of session register.   Let me know if this solves